Android Fresco - "ClassNotFoundException: androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface" only on some devices
Recently I start to receive some bug report for some of my apps regarding a missing androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface class.
The odd thing is that this seems to happens only for some specific devices.
I think this exception occurs at Android Fresco 's pipeline initialization phase, i.e. Fresco.initialize(...)
A. Trying to solve the problem in blind mode - does not work :/
As I don't really know what's going on, I did the following changes in my gradle config:

In my /gradle/libs.versions.toml have added
[versions]
exifinterface = "1.3.7"
...
[libraries]
androidx-exifinterface = { module = "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface", version.ref = "exifinterface" }


and also added ,in the build.gradle file of my library project, this:
api libs.androidx.exifinterface



B. Maybe using R8/Proguard
Not sure.. and which Proguard statements should I use ..?? 
Something like this ???
-keep class androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface { *; }
-keepclassmembers class androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface { *; }

C. Begging for help

Did any of you encountered this issue?
If yes, how did you solved it?

Note:
I created an issue on Fresco's Github https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/2810
FYI, the stack trace, which occurs in the "FrescoIoBoundExecutor" thread
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface
 [wrapped] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface;
        at c6.b.a(b.java:8)
        at v5.f.l(f.java:482)
        at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.LocalFetchProducer.d(LocalFetchProducer.java:162)
        at com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.SwallowResultProducer.run(SwallowResultProducer.java:12)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.android.material.datepicker.DateFormatTextWatcher.lambda$new$0(DateFormatTextWatcher.java:72)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$onBackPressedDispatcher$2$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(ComponentActivity.java:0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

